# Selecting a DTO object from an entity framework query where most properties are the same, is there a better way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So, I have the following EF query:

```
private List<PolysubByYearDto> buildDtos(IQueryable<vw_Polysub> polysubs)
        {
            var query = from p in polysubs
                         join c in uowTr.CountyRepository.List() on p.primary_cty equals c.County_Code into lj1
                         from polysubWithCounty in lj1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join t in uowTr.PolysubRepository.ListPolyType() on p.poly_type_cd equals t.poly_type_cd into lj2
                         from polysubWithType in lj2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join period in uowTr.PolysubRepository.ListReportPeriods() on p.rec_no equals period.rec_no into lj3
                         from polysubWithPeriod in lj3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new PolysubByYearDto()
                        {
                            PrimaryCountyName = (polysubWithCounty == null ? String.Empty : polysubWithCounty.county_name),
                            PolyTypeName = (polysubWithType == null ? String.Empty : polysubWithType.poly_name_ds),
                            ReportYearEndMonth = ((polysubWithPeriod == null || !polysubWithPeriod.year_end_month.HasValue) ? 0 : polysubWithPeriod.year_end_month.Value),
                            taxrate_year = p.taxrate_year
                            //taxrate_year and every property to follow (a lot) are all from the vw_Polysub object
                            //and share the same names as the PolysubByYearDto object properties...
                            // is there a better way to just make them all map without explicitly naming all properties?
                        };

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

The comment inside the "select" explains my problem. The PolysubByYearDto class is a child of vw_Polysub so it contains all of the same properties plus 3 more. Those 3 properties are set from joined data in the query, but every single property afterward just requires parent to child object property mapping. There are many properties and they all share the same names. Is there a way to do this without explicitly naming every property? The vw_Polysub object is generated from a view so it doesn't have reference properties which is why I had to join the data. I do not want to .toList() the query and then use reflection/automapper to map the properties because of performance reasons, I want the PolysubByYearDto objects to come out of the database. Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: there are quite a few frameworks that try to automate this boilerplate notion.  But, 'Is there a better way' is a off-topic\dont-ask topic to SO.  It invites subjective, non-concise answers and opinions.  please review help articles for [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I had a look through that page already and came to the conclusion automapper isn't what I want because I'm explicitly joining to other data rather than using reference properties. Is that not the case?

Comment: @BrettCaswell Okay, how about is there ANY way given the other requirements that I mentioned?

Comment: I guess that could work _somehow_, but yes, it helps to have FKs :) I would add them if I were you, save you a lot of pain.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I can't add reference properties because the parent object is an entity generated from a database view, not a table.

Comment: well.. that probably isn't much better (see what I did there :D ).. but I can tell you an alternative approach here would be code generation.  In a Database-First EF6 implementation (old now), there were T4 templates to generate entities based on schema (as well as the context that use those types), but with a few tweaks you could generate Dto types unrelated to the types used in the context.  in that respect, you can create Extension Methods and\or type constructors on types.  Of course, you don't need schema or a DB First approach, you could T4 and reflect on types in loaded assemblies.

Comment: I don't think views are a problem. Whatever works with EF, works with `ProjectTo`. I'm sure with a little research you can find what you need.